# Wrong encoding in orientjs when using emoticon

Tags: encoding, orientdb, orientjs

I have some encoding problem.

If I use simple emoticon as ♬ it's working.

For emoji like  :

If I use OrientDB Console, no problem for me to update some rows with emoticone characters.

If I use OrientJs, I can't make it work : ' is transformed into ���� (so each emoticone seems to be encoded in two parts).

If it helps I'm using 
    db.update('Card').set(card)...
or 
    db.insert('Card').set(card)...

What shall I change in the config to make it work ? How can I change the way the data is serialized ?

Thanks !